# Who plays the Auctioneer?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In the film The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies, who plays the role of the Auctioneer who is in charge of disposing of Bilbo's house and belonging?

Was it [Ian McNiece](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0573862/) from Doc Martin or someone else?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for the name of the actor?

Comment: A surprisingly hard question to answer. In the books he was a Mr Grubb.

Comment: Ian McNeice wasn't the auctioneer, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yup, @Richard's right. He isn't [credited on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0573862/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) for the role. But I can't seem to find who is either.

Comment: The only thing I can find is Merv Smith, I haven't seen the movie yet so I don't know if I'm right http://www.reallife.net.nz/site/reallife.net.nz/filesystem/images/merv-smith.jpg

Comment: @Richard or perhaps Mr Burrowes.

Comment: @EricSSH - Merv Smith is credited as the elder Mr Grubb (Grub) on IMDB, not the younger Mr Grubb (the auctioneer).

Comment: @EricSSH -http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Tosser_Grubb

Comment: You're right it is difficult to determine as there is nothing on imdb for this small part.

Comment: It's Johnny Depp in weird prosthetic makeup. Just Kidding.

Comment: My guess is that Merv Smith played both Mr Grubb the elder **AND** Mr Grubb the auctioneer. Firstly, it would make sense to use the same actor to represent close family relations (physical likeness and all that); secondly, it's a movie...how often do production staff mess around with stories and characters and forget about consistency? They probably named both those characters Tosser Grub.

Comment: @user35594 - I'm thinking it might be. There's a resemblance and the actor has a ton of makeup on their face. The "appearance" order is correct as well. IF no better/more canonical answer pops up, I'll award the bounty to indeed's answer below.

Comment: @Richard - Doubt we will ever know unless it comes from an official source. But an interesting question nonetheless!

Comment: @user35594 - Under the circumstances, I'll be awarding the bounty to indeed, unless an alternative proposition is raised.

Comment: @Richard, indeed was the first to post a plausible answer so it's only fair to receive the bounty aswell :)

Answer (score 9):

According to the DVD subtitles, the person who Bilbo meets going up the hill is Worrywort and the auctioneer is Tosser.

[image]

[image]

The actor is therefore confirmed as Mervyn Smith.

Comment: "Tosser".  Fnarr fnarr.

Comment: You have my upvote and shall receive the bounty accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Based on what I could find I'd say it's probably Mervyn (Merv) Smith.

On the IMDb [full cast & crew page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2310332/fullcredits/) Mervyn (Merv) Smith is credited as Tosser Grub (although this list is awaiting verification). [Peter Jackson's The Hobbit Wiki](http://peter-jacksons-the-hobbit.wikia.com/wiki/Merv_Smith) states that Merv Smith portrays Tosser Grubb in *The Battle of Five Armies* as well as the extended edition of *An Unexpected Journey*. If this is the same character it would mean that he turned grey over the course of Bilbo's journey.

I checked the credits for *An Unexpected Journey* (see first image below, bottom right) where Tosser Grubb is listed as portrayed by Mervyn Smith, the same goes for the *The Battle of Five Armies* credits (second image).

[image: Credits for The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey]
[image: Credits for The Hobbit: The Battle of Five Armies]

Comment: As I said in my earlier comment, I'm fairly convinced that the character of Tosser Grubb is who Bilbo meets on the way up the hill, not the auctioneer. They certainly don't look alike.

Comment: I only saw that comment after I posted my answer. The Hobbit you're referring to looks more like [Master Worrywort](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Worrywort) to me.
edit: [screenshot](https://40.media.tumblr.com/e7a3bbf64790b0a7daffa1a7b451e040/tumblr_niqqbdMUAV1qc8b4ko1_1280.jpg)

Comment: Ah, you're not wrong there.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer but awarded the bounty to @indeed (for being the first to spot the change to the wikia).

Answer (score 3):

Going off the cast listing [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2310332/fullcredits/) and the mentioning of the auctioneer in charge of the selling of Bilbo's possessions [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Tosser_Grubb), I would say that the auctioneer was played by **Merv Smith** (as mentioned by EricSSH in the comments).

Comment: Except that it's [not the same person](http://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/6/63/The_Hobbit_-_An_Unexpected_Journey_-_Tosser_Grubb.jpg)!

Comment: Oh indeed! Well, I tried.

Comment: This is one of those cases where you need to "beware of the wiki". From what I can tell, Tosser Grubb is who Bilbo speaks to when he's on the way up the hill, not the auctioneer.

Comment: Yet it says on that wiki that Tosser Grubb is the auctioneer and the person Bilbo speaks to.

Comment: The problem with a wiki is that anyone write anything, without any proof.

Comment: Yes, it appears that has happened here. So we may never know who did actually play the role of the auctioneer, since its not listed on the official cast.

Comment: @Richard ... It has to be one of two Grubbs or a Burrowes ... look at the bottom  of the picture in the question. The sign reads: "*Grubbs, Grubbs, and Burrowes Registered Auctioneers*" ... But I doubt you missed this. It could be the unnamed Grubbs, but this still doesn't get us any closer to verifying the actor.

Comment: @indeed - Under the circumstances, I've decided to award you the bounty. I've not seen a definitive proof but your link to the wikia is certainly the closest we've come so far. I might revisit this when the director's commentary comes out.

Comment: Well thank you, and the directors commentary definitely seems like a good way to go to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the actor above *is* Merv Smith. Here are pictures of him:

[image] [image]

Look at the jowls. Then put a prosthetic nose on him. Merv also has a gobbler chin as well.

Comment: Well, they're definitely not the same actors. So if Merv Griffin IS playing Tosser Grubb (the auctioneer), then the guy sitting at the table in the first movie is NOT Tosser Grubb.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you on that point. I'm saying the guy above appears to be the Auctioneer. Since Merv Griffin is credited with playing Tosser Grubb and the above person is Merv Griffin, I don't think the picture which Richard linked to is actually Tosser Grubb and someone on the wiki site got it wrong ... but, I think that's what you are saying as well.

Comment: How is this different from the other two answer that say he is Merv,  but it is mentioned on both that he isnt?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic ... Pictures are worth a thousand words. This is Merv Smith (sorry, screwed up the name in my other comment). It appears to me to be the Auctioneer. This answers the question and does it without conjecture. If the other answers had at least inks to pictures of Merv, I never would have posted this. It is more conclusive and answers the question directly.

Comment: So what we really need to figure out is whether or not the auctioneer is Tosser Grubb. He could easily be the other Grubb or Mr. Burrowes.

Comment: @Omegacron ... Deduction would tell me if Tosser Grubb was played by Merv Smith, and the auctioneer and Merv Smith pictures being the same person, the auctioneer was Tosser Grubb. The original wiki link provided by EricSSH has the wrong actor/character picture in it. I think that is the real question at this point.

Comment: So, where the heck is Merv Smith in the first movie?

Answer (score -3):

I reckon the auctioneer is played by Toby Jones, compare the voice and accent with his role as Lance in the detectorists (BBC TV series).

Comment: Why do think this is the answer as opposed to the accepted answer, which has pretty solid proof that the actor is Mervyn Smith?